# Credit score and financing new car

Tags: credit-score, car, credit-history, down-payment, financing

Little bit about my situation-

Bought a car with cash about 5 years ago, at the time it was a year old. That car is now a total loss and I’m receiving about 5k for it from my insurance. I’m now in need of a car and thinking about putting the money back as a down payment and financing a new car. The only issue is my credit score is at 590 (coming out of college). I don’t want to put the money back into an old used car that will cost me money in repairs.

Should I pay off all of my credit cards with the money back from my insurance (it would cover all of my credit card debt) and save for a down payment for a few months (while borrowing a friend’s car in the meantime). This would boost my credit score and possibly put me at a better chance of getting a lower interest rate

OR

Should I use the money for a down payment and finance a 1-2 yr old car? My only worry with this option is having higher interest rates due to my current credit score

Comment: What's your credit utilization at currently (total card balance over total available credit)?

Comment: About 97% right now 

Comment: Is borrowing your friend's car actually a feasible solution? That is, will it be available for your use often enough and for long enough to suit your needs? Could this friend change their mind a week or two (or months) down the road, leaving you without transportation?

Comment: Possibly yes. The friend is currently in between jobs but as soon as they get a job they’ll need their vehicle again

Comment: You can buy many perfectly good cars for under $5K.  The "cost me money in repairs" is really not something to worry about.  Of course things can happen (as you apparently found out), but overall the money saved on higher purchase price & interest will almost certainly be more than the likely cost of repairs.

Comment: I will be honest and say I do not want to buy a car worth 5k or less. I would rather sacrifice a few months being without a car and using public transportation, if it means I’ll be better suited for a newer car purchase in a few months. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: How much of the 5K will you have left after paying off the CC debt?

Comment: you can't have your cake and eat it too. Take care of your debt, and that might mean settling for a less flashy car.

Comment: @user87816: So you'd rather mooch off your friend?  I wonder how long this friend is going to remain a friend.  Of course you could buy the cheap car, drive it until your credit cards are paid off &c, then use it as a trade-in on the more expensive one.

Comment: Having being severely in CC debt myself about 10 years ago, to the point I was barely able to afford paying the interest (repaying capital, lol, in my dreams!), I don't even consider it a choice. You get rid of the CC debt and save up. That's the only sensible option. You're in a position to wipe your debt; DO IT!

Comment: "I don't want" is often not a good advice, financially spoken.

Comment: You are currently in some severe debt. Do everything in your power to avoid more debt. Get an amicable and reliable agreement with a friend to help you out. Make sure to pay them for their assistance. If you choose to finance a car then you're choosing to extend your suffering. If you choose to pay off this severe debt then your suffering should only be temporary. Remember, there will never be a shortage of lenders that want to put you in debt so getting a car a later date is always an option.

Comment: @jamesqf I disagree. If it costs less than $5k, it's very likely not a "perfectly good car". It might be an "ok" car or even a "good" car, but there's bound to be _something_ wrong with it...

Comment: @only_pro If it gets you safely from home to work daily in a place where transit or cycling is unfeasible, then it does 100% of what is needed and is thus perfectly good for its purpose.

Comment: it also sounds like you could do without a car. In that case, you could do just that, save the insurance, gas, maintenance, and loan, and get out of your CC debt.

Comment: Keep in mind that even if you improve your credit score, you still won't get great car loan rates because you have never had a car loan before.  You are a "first time buyer" with no large loan experience.

Answer (score 42):

CC debt is **My Hair Is On Fire!!** debt, because the interest rate is so high.

So... yes, you should pay that off first (unless you like subsidizing my 1.5% Cash Back Rewards and "Fat Cat Bankers" while slowly impoverishing yourself).

Comment: That is what I’m inclining towards but I just don’t know how long I’ll be able to borrow my friend’s car for work so it’s anxiety inducing

Comment: I speak from personal experience when I say that when you're in deep debt, none of your options are good.

Comment: If you haven't already done so, go through your budget with a fine toothed comb.  Leave a *small* amount for enjoyment, but for a while you'll have to live lean.  Unless, of course, you want to light your hair on fire again...

Comment: I don't necessarily agree that CC debt = hair on fire, however, with the added detail of 97% utilization, I would say all of OP's hair (head and body) is on fire.

Comment: @stannius the APR on that card is a least 18%.  I wouldn't be surprised if it's 23% or higher.  To me, that qualifies as hair on fire.

Comment: Normally I'd agree with this, but since the OP doesn't have a car to get to work, and borrowing a car that their friend might need at any time, I'd say that needing reliable transportation is more important right now than credit card debt. If the OP can't get to work, they can't get paid.

Comment: @computercarguy with a better credit score, you can borrow at a lower interest rate. (That's my rationalization, at least.)

Comment: @RonJohn, normally this would something I'd suggest, too. Unfortunately, with this amount of money vs. CC debt vs. car debt, it's still a losing battle. Even at a lower rate for a car loan, the OP'll still pay more in interest on the life of the car loan than they are likely to save on the CC debt.

Comment: @computercarguy: But there's no reason for the OP to go into car debt.  He has about $5K from the insurance payout, and my local Craigslist has ~75 pages of just Hondas and Toyotas for under $2K.  These would serve perfectly well to get him to work and back until he pays off his CC debt.

Comment: @jamesqf, you are correct that the OP doesn't have to go into debt to get a car, however if they pay off their CC debt, they likely won't have any money left for the car. Not with their 97% credit utilization. Take a look at my Answer for what my full "solution" is.

Comment: The OP also states that they could use public transportation. That's almost certainly the answer-- pay off the CC debt, don't worry about buying a car for now, take public transportation, and save up for the car down the line. I saved an enormous amount of money using buses and trains for ~10 years after college, and only bought a car when public transit wasn't a realistic option for a new job.

Comment: @Upper_Case: Of course there's the question of whether public transportation would be cheaper than a cheap used car (especially considering the value of time), but that's very much dependent on location.

Comment: @jamesqf Definitely a calculation worth making. But cars are fairly expensive to own, even if the purchase price is low. Gas, routine maintenance, registration, insurance, parking-- it can easily end up in the thousands per year, indefinitely, without even considering acute, expensive events (like crashes, vandalism, etc.). And I agree about the value of time, but I personally found that transit service on the order of every ~30 minutes was reasonably comparable for trips I *had* to make. Obviously that won't be everyone's experience.

Answer (score 20):

You're asking several related questions - about credit scores, how to use cash, and how to buy a vehicle.

If we break them all down and start with what to do with your $5k in cash - it makes sense to use that to pay down credit card debt, since it's likely costing you an arm and a leg in interest right now. Even if you decide you need a vehicle badly, and can afford monthly payments on a vehicle loan, paying down the credit card debt and then immediately borrowing money will mean you're paying a low-interest auto loan rate instead of a high interest on the credit card.

The good news is, paying off your credit card debt will likely have a big, positive impact on your credit score. In a comment, you mentioned that your utilization is around 97% right now. That's going to make a **huge** impact on a credit score. Utilization is one of the heaviest-weighted factors in typical models, and 97% effectively puts you in the worst-scoring bracket. The good news is, *utilization is memoryless* so within a month of you paying off your balances, your score will instantly pop up as if that high utilization had never happened.

While on the subject of credit scores, it's worth getting information on your credit report to understand why it's so low. As mentioned, utilization is likely a big impact, but since it sounds like you're young and don't have a long (10+ years) credit history, there may be other factors influencing your score as well. Use a free service like creditkarma, or request a free report directly from the major bureaus. If there are things you don't understand in your report, ask specific questions here. Now - while you're young - is a good time to establish good habits.

Finally, you've asked about buying a vehicle. These questions are a little hard to answer because there will always be some subjectivity and personal preference. Some people will be risk-averse enough that buying or leasing a cheaper new car (and the warranty that comes with it) will be a benefit over paying cash for an old used car. Still other people will want a certain vehicle, or certain features, or will want to change vehicles more or less frequently. Really, before you decide on buying old, financing to buy new, or leasing, you need to decide what's important to you in terms of the vehicle you want, and what you can afford in terms of down payment and/or monthly cash flow, and then you can pick the best approach to getting yourself there.

Comment: That is great news about credit utilization being “memoryless”. I definitely was inclining towards using the money to pay off my CC debt first. As for my personal preference, I mentioned in a previous comment that I would want to buy something newer (within 1-4/5 yrs range). I do use Experian to view my credit report. Utilization and old debt history is what’s impacting my credit the most.

Comment: Is there any tool to see what my credit score would be if I paid off my total CC debt?

Comment: No such tool that I'm aware of - it would be hard to build such a tool since it would mean running your entire report through a scoring model before and after the change. Also, many real-world events will tie into multiple factors (paying off a credit card drops your utilization *and* your total debt, which are separate factors). Tools like creditkarma will help you understand factors relative to each other, which can at least help you get a rough idea of what to focus on.

Comment: Anecdotally though, I've seen cases where someone paying off several credit cards at once raised their score by more than 150 points. And other cases where doing so only changed a score by a few dozen points.

Comment: @user87816 Capital One includes simulation of paying off debt/taking new loans/etc on the credit monitoring tool they provide to card members.  It looks like the simulator may be available without having a card from them:    https://creditwise.capitalone.com/home

Comment: @DanNeely: yup - a lot of banks are adding these tools now. One thing to be wary of is that some of them use their own algorithms, so don't get too hung up on the exact numerical changes... just use them to get a sense of things.

Comment: @Dancrumb true enough, although at least one (IIRC several) of my cards have gone from offering presumably in house designed fake-o credit scores derived from Bureau X's data initially to actual Bureau X FICO scores afterward.  From my perspective the situation's gotten better over the last few years; but that could just be due to the subset of banks I do business with.

Answer (score 10):

Do not buy a car on credit. Ever. The fact that you have credit card debt makes it an even worse idea, but there are just so many reasons you should never buy a car on credit. For $5000 you can get a great, excellent-condition car. You could probably even get one for $3500-4000 and put the rest towards paying off the credit cards.

> I don’t want to put the money back into an old used car that will cost me money in repairs.

New cars cost **more** in repairs.

Comment: +1, there are reasons to buy a new car, but saving money is not one of them.

Comment: **+1** Exactly! As soon as your credit-bought car becomes a total loss, you need a new car **while still being bound to pay off your wrecked old car**.

Comment: @Niko1978 that's what insurance is for.

Comment: *Do not buy a car on credit. Ever.* This seems like narrow advice that doesn't really address the OP's reality. If they were happy with a $5k car (they've said they aren't, by the way), they'd be *much* better off putting the $5k cash against their credit cards, and then borrowing $5k on a car loan (at a vastly lower rate than their credit card).

Comment: @dwizum An insurance company may pay out way less for the totalled car though, than your remaining debt.

Comment: Borrowing on the car, or paying for it in cash, doesn't have anything to do with being under-insured. If you pay $5k cash for a car, and then total it the next day, your assets are still taking the same hit as if you'd borrowed to buy it - it's just a hit you've already paid for. If you're worried about a loss from totaling the car, *get it properly insured* regardless of if it's financed or not.

Comment: New cars require less maintenance than older cars, which makes them cost **less** in repairs. Also, I don't think he was suggesting that he would buy the care on a credit card, but rather that he could put the cash on his credit card to pay it down and buy it with a conventional car loan.

Comment: @Ben: That's false on two bases. (1) New cars have problems requiring service at similar rates to decent used cars, typically 1-2 incidents per year. Warranty might cover them for a new car, but dealers will do their best to make you end up paying for something, and pressure you to use their scheduled service (at exorbitant rates) to retain the warranty protection, or claim that if you did the scheduled maintenance yourself or somewhere else, it was done wrong and voided the warranty. And their maintenance schedule itself is way more expensive than typical problems with a good used car.

Comment: (2) The parts and service for new cars cost **a lot** more than the parts and service for somewhat older cars. Often 5 to 10 times as much. Even if you had fewer service incidents, you'd end up paying a lot more total.

Comment: @R.., I'm not sure why you would think new cars break down at the same rate of old cars, but you're [just wrong.](https://www.consumerreports.org/car-maintenance/the-cost-of-car-ownership/)

Comment: @Ben: From the experiences of literally every single person I know who buys them. It't not usually "breaking down" in terms of "can't go anywhere". It's things like window motors, sensors that make the CEL light go off, etc. The worst part is that, as a non-expert, you can't tell if the lights going off are just nags for scheduled maintenance or indicative of an actual problem.

Comment: @R.. I have purchased 2 new cars in the past 3 years and have had exactly one sensor go bad (which only cost me $100 to fix, $60 for an OBD scanner and $40 for the sensor itself). The VAST majority of damage to the cars has been incidental road damage (stick on the 402 returning from Niagra Falls busted a sensor on the car front axle, rock from a construction truck cracked a windshield, fender damage from a snow plow). New cars carry much lower maintenance costs. That being said, 1-5 years old are still very low maintenance, and have already been lot-depreciated.

Comment: @GOATNine, I agree, but his point is that maintenance costs are the same for new cars and old cars. I personally buy the 1-3 year old cars, but I disagree that there's not difference maintenance wise between a new car and a 10 year old car.

Comment: @Ben a 10 yr old car will carry higher maintenance costs if it isn't well cared for. Buying a 10 yr old car is like rolling the dice, even with services that do a history check on their maintenance and repairs, unless you know the person selling you the car and know they've kept up on it. Case and point, my 3 year old car only has 45k miles on it, but I know the clutch feels more like 100k miles because of how I drive stick. That won't be evident until about 2-3 years from now, and I won't disclose it if I don't have to during a sale.

Comment: @GOATNine: OTOH, my current vehicles range from 17 to 31 years old, and I spend very little on repairs.

Comment: @jamesqf you must take great care of them then! That's a good thing.

Comment: Mine are similar, and I really don't take good care of them at all. Over the past 10 years, I've spent something like $3500 on maintenance for a car I spent $1000 to purchase, and like 2/3 of that was on ridiculous prices for AC stuff. It could easily have been $6000+ if I had professionals do it, but average of $600/year is still **way** below costs of owning a new car.

Comment: @GOATNine: Not so much that I take care of them, though I do enjoy doing mechanical work.  It's that they're made by Honda, Toyota, and Mazda.

Answer (score 3):

> I would rather sacrifice a few months being without a car and using public transportation (to get a better car later)

Do you need a car at all?  In this modern world of lyft and lime and uber and boom and whatever the scooters and on-demand rideshares in your area are called, then do a **cost analysis** and see if you're better off without a car.

Work in all the running/owning/licencing/insurance costs of a car, and compare that annual cost with however much it would be to use an on-demand service, or to buy your own scooter/e-scooter or bike for short trips.

Your credit score will benefit from not having additional debt - and from some points of view, a car is a liability not an asset.  And in the meantime your down-payment dollars can be working for you elsewhere.

Comment: Where I live lyft and uber are not options. I would say that in most places (not big cities), they are not viable options even short term.

Comment: Using taxis/Lyft/Uber/etc on a daily basis is not going to be viable. Even if it's "only" $8 a ride, that add up quickly, especially if you need to go several places in a day. Seeing as the OP wants an expensive new car, they aren't likely to want a scooter. Not to mention that scooters can also be expensive and are unsafe, due to other drivers not paying attention.

Comment: @computercarguy Its definitely worth doing the numbers - makes financial sense to spend $8 a ride if you only use it once a week.  Makes sense to buy a bike/scooter if there's only ever one person in the car.   Its worth checking out for completeness if nothing else.

Comment: @Criggie, if it was even likely the OP was going to accept a scooter as an option, it be good to do the math, but not as it stands. Since they are currently borrowing a car instead of already riding public transportation (as mentioned they'd do in a comment), it's highly likely they need a ride more than just once a week. It's pretty easy to drop $500-1000 on restaurant food in a month at $5-10 a meal, so an Uber at $5-10 a day can be just as expensive, which doesn't help with saving for a car. I'm not against "doing the math", but it's not likely to come out nicely, is all.

Comment: @computercarguy *$500-1000 on restaurant food in a month at $5-10 a meal*, 100 restaurant meals per month?  How?

Comment: @computercarguy That's why public transportation exists. When I was so far in debt that I could barely cope with it, I used the bus, my bike, and my feet to go everywhere. It cost me 80$/month and that's one of the main reasons I was able to repay >$10k CC debt in about 2 years and end up with almost $10k in savings instead. I ate lots of ramen too, but I still went to the restaurant regularly. It was all the transportation costs that translated to saving.

Comment: @gerrit, even if you try to stick to $5-10 a meal, it's not always going to be that little, and at 3 meals a day for 30 days, that's 90 meals. It's way too easy to pay more for food than you like to think, especially if you do a $5 coffee. I've spent $900 on food in a month for just myself before, and I didn't even go to fancy restaurants.

Comment: @GabrielC., sure. I've used public trans. when I first moved to Las Vegas, but it took about an hour to go anywhere. Also, not everywhere has even decent public trans. Most of the places I've lived had so few buses that it was rare to see them driving around, and trains/subways weren't a thing. It's great you were able to use them and save so much, but that's not going to happen with everyone.

Comment: @computercarguy Sure, but who eats in restaurants three times a day for a month?  100 times per month is *more* than three times per day on average. Yes, if you do that you can save money, like [this guy can on water](https://xkcd.com/1715/).

Comment: @gerrit, I guess you've completely missed my point: something that seems inexpensive once can really add up if done a lot.

Comment: @computercarguy Eating in restaurants three times a day every day seems incredibly expensive to me, as of course is commuting by taxi. I've never heard of anyone doing either (except perhaps the very rich).

Comment: @computercarguy That's why I said bus + bike + feet. Some places are more easily/quickly accessible by bike. One gets the added benefit of saving on gym subscription too. The OP mentioned public transportation (as in this answer's quote) and nowhere did Criggie say you should solely rely on "rideshare" taxi services. That's what you're missing in gerrit's argument. You could use it a few times a month, using more inexpensive means for the rest.

Comment: @gerrit, it was. I'd get breakfast and lunch at the company cafeteria, then a simple sub for supper. I only did it for 3 months before I figured out how much I was spending. It was too much, so I quit. This is why I know how much and how easily a person can spend on food in a month. This is also why I compared it to taking Uber/taxi/etc. I'm trying to agree with you that it's too expensive, but you keep arguing with me about a simple range I gave.

Comment: @GabrielC., Criggie seems to think that estimating the cost of rideshares is going to be a 100% guarantee of being accurate with how much a person will use it. By my experience, people way underestimate how much they use things. And not every place is easily accessible by bike, or even bus + bike. And you seem to be missing my point, that "small" towns don't have good public trans, but can still be spread out far enough that biking isn't viable, not to mention weather considerations and the effect of sweating in an office environment.

Comment: @computercarguy When you make a budget but don't follow it, it's not the budget that's at fault. I assume your experience with underestimations is personal? Maybe you lacked motivation. Poverty and/or extreme debt is a **very** good motivator.

Comment: @GabrielC. I grew up poor, I had bad paying jobs until about 3 years ago, and I pay attention to other people's estimations of things. I've also had lots of credit card and student loan debt that caused my bills to exceed my income by $300 a month. Go ahead and keep assuming things that have nothing to do with what I've said, since it says more about you than it does me.

Comment: @computercarguy: While I agree about weather, the distance you can bike (once you get in decent shape) is further than you may think.  My longest regular bike commute was 17 miles, generally done in a bit less than an hour.  These days many offices do have showersfor bikers,  people who exercise at lunch, &c.

Comment: @jamesqf, showers at work is not a guarantee. The only place I've worked that had showers eventually removed them due to lack of use. Also, assuming it won't take months or years for someone to get into "decent shape" is a stretch. Geography also plays a factor, such as massive hills, bridges without safe walkways, and more. Some places just aren't well suited for bike travel.

Comment: Millions of Dutch commute by bike and almost none take showers at work, but of course The Netherlands has excellent cycling infrastructure, which most of the USA does not — the threshold is much higher there, but there are still many more who could bike to work, than who do.

Answer (score 2):

97% credit utilization is definitely driving your credit score down significantly, utilization accounts for 30% of your credit score. More importantly though is the high interest rate of credit card debt. The ideal is of course to pay off that credit card debt as quickly as possible to minimize interest. If you can get around without a car by using public transportation or a bike for a while then you should embrace the inconvenience and get rid of the credit card debt. Then save up for a car purchase.

Counting on borrowing a car doesn't seem like a good solution. If you absolutely need a car then a good compromise is probably reserving enough for a 10% down payment on a relatively inexpensive used car and using the rest to pay down credit card debt. Even if you don't get a very good rate on your car loan, you'll be saving money compared to your credit card rates. Much better to pay 6% interest on a car loan than 18% on credit card debt.

All cars will have repairs, and newer cars almost always cost more to insure than older cars, so it doesn't necessarily make sense to focus on a 1-2 year old car. If I were in your situation I'd go for an older car known for reliability, there are plenty of quite old cars that don't necessarily look great or have many features that still run reliably. Years ago I got a ~15 year old car and drove it for 5+ years with very little maintenance cost. Certainly lucky that it lasted so long, but I see plenty of older cars driving around every day. Thanks to the internet you can likely tackle a lot of little repairs yourself to save even more.

Comment: I mentioned in an above comment that I would prefer not to buy a car worth 5k or less. I would rather sacrifice a few months being without a car and use public transportation or ask relatives for a temporary car. I will most likely pay off the debt first & save for a down payment in the meantime

Comment: That's understandable, and that's part of why I mentioned just reserving enough for a 10% down payment, if you find something in the 10-15k range that means 1-1.5k down payment and 3.5-4k toward credit card debt. Per the first paragraph though, waiting on the car purchase is certainly ideal if you can swing it.

Comment: *waiting on the car purchase is certainly ideal if you can swing it* - absolutely - if not for the purpose of saving up a downpayment, then certainly because waiting will improve your credit score (assuming you've paid off the credit cards and don't do anything foolish in the meantime).

Answer (score 2):

1. 1-2 year old car ??? why ? You can easily get a reliable 5 year old car. Depreciation on 1-2 year old cars is ridiculous.
2. 590 credit score with 97% utilization is pretty good. Depending on your credit limit paying off $5000 of that will increase your score a lot.

So imho you should use the money to pay off some credit cards, then (after they report current balance) buy a decent car with little to no money down.

Most importantly, though, you need to work on the credit card debt. You're probably costing yourself thousands of dollars a year that you don't have to spend. Imagine saving that money (or better, imagine investing that money and getting about 4x that money over the next 40 years).

Answer (score 2):

Get in debt to buy a car is not a option to me, even more if you have credit cards to pay.
First of all, you need to analyse if you really need a car where you live, considering cost/benefit.
My advise is get out of debt and if you are sure about needing a car, so buy a cheap one.
Finally, work hard to increse your income so this kind of thing is not a problem in your life anymore.

Answer (score 1):

My experience says to spend $2000-3000 on a reliable, used car and keep the rest for immediate repairs on the car.  Also, use this money as a safety net for other expenses that come up, so you can pay cash for it, instead of add to your credit card debt.

I know this sounds somewhat backwards, but here's my reasoning.

Your credit doesn't matter right now. Your spending habits do.  If all you want are expensive things that you can't afford without going into debt, then you are always going to have bad credit, no money, and you'll be working your whole life to afford things you bought years ago.  You need to address this version of materialism before it gets you in serious trouble.

A cheap but reliable car is going to save you money in the short and long term, even if you need to fix it right away. Dropping $200 on repairs in a month isn't fun, but a $250 monthly payment is worse.  The money you save on car payments can go towards your credit card debt, saving you lots of money in a short time.

Let's do some math.

At $250 a month for a car payment (really, a modest payment for a new car and a low credit rating), you will take 20 months to regain $5000.  This mean you might be borrowing your friend's car or taking a bus for almost 2 years if you put all your money on the credit cards. Or, you can make your life easier and buy the cheap car and take those same 2 years to pay down/off the credit cards.

Again, taking 2 years to pay off credit cards when you might be able to pay them off now seems backwards, but there's reasons for my "madness". If you pay off the CC's, you may have the idea that it's OK to use those credit cards again, which gets you back to where you are now, just with more stuff and no $5k. You still won't have a car, you're still borrowing a car or taking the bus, and you still aren't saving for a car due to new credit card bills.

Think of your situation as a hole in the ground, because debt really is this way.  Unless you have the ability to jump completely clear of the hole, you're just going to land on the edge, grasping for anything to hold onto before you fall back in, probably taking a bunch of dirt with you, burying you further and making it harder to dig out. Instead, make thought out plans on how to get out of debt and follow the plans, until it's time to change your plan. Digging out slowly means you are less likely to have the hole fall in on your, burying you again.

Since you are just out of college, you have plenty of time to get out of debt, get a nice car, and all the other things you want, but you have to do it intelligently. A cheap, reliable car will save you a lot more money than buying a new car. Even $1000 a year in repairs is less costly than $3000 in monthly payments, repairs, and higher insurance.

When someone talks about credit card debt and trying to afford things like a car, I always point to the book ["America's Cheapest Family"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0307339459). I don't get anything for "advertising" for this book, I'm simply another satisfied customer. (Any referral is not mine, as SE/SO has added them to my posts previously.)

This family has several kids, a low income, and finds ways to afford new cars, houses, moving across the country, taking vacations, and more.  Most of my advice comes from this book mixed with my own experience. This family also helps others fix their finances in their own real life, so it's not just a bunch of ideals that don't work. This book is filled with examples of how to save money, yes, but it comes from a lot of experience, trials, failures, successes, and time. They make it interesting, since they include their own life experiences in the examples, rather than it just being a dry "financials" textbook. I've read the book twice and it helped me figure out a few more things to get me out of credit card and student loan debt.

Well, good luck and I hope I helped!

Comment: You're making the assumption that the car will be reliable and that nothing will happen to it. If OP is unlucky and gets wrecked by a careless driver or if his seemingly fine car turns out to crap out quickly, then he's out the car's cost and **still** in debt, super close to the CC credit limit. That's a risky, unsafe gamble.

Comment: @GabrielC. I said to buy the car outright with the $5k the OP has, not to buy on credit like everyone else does. With a car purchased outright, insurance is going to payout to the owner, not the creditor. I also said to keep the remainder for repairs. Many repairs can be done by an owner, as I've done with the majority of my cars. I've kept cars going to 215k miles and owned them for 10-15 years, even when bought used. An accident can happen anywhere, anytime, and it's going to cost you regardless. Not to mention that it's going to cost more than the $5k put towards the CCs.

Comment: I'd agree with buying the $2K car, but use the other $3K to pay down the credit cards.  That starts saving interest right away, and if the car does need repairs, they can be on the credit cards again.

Comment: @jamesqf, putting car repairs on CC's just reinforces the need and use of the CC's. The way to pay off that debt is to learn how not to rely on it. Continually relying on CC's will cost you more in interest than not using them again.

Comment: @computercarguy: I disagree.  A car repair is an emergency expense, and in this case, an unlikely one.  So the OP has a choice between retaining cash while continuing to pay interest on $3K of existing credit card debt, or paying off that debt now, with the option of putting the possible future expense on a card.  Seems like an obvious choice to me.

Comment: @jamesqf, having a cash safety net has been promoted by more financially intelligent people than me. It's about the only thing that financial advisers agree on for being financially stable. It may seem like having cash on hand is stupid when you're paying interest on CC debt, but it's really the only thing that keeps you from continuing to charge on the CCs and continuing to pay more interest. It's funny that you say car repair is unlikely when Gabriel C. seemed to think it was eminent. I know that it's guaranteed to be needed, and often without warning. Cash is best, believe it.

Comment: @computercarguy: I strongly doubt that having the cash safety net and high interest credit card debt go together.  If "financial advisors" are really saying this, they're IMHO giving bad advice.  (My personal finances are doing quite well without their advice, BTW :-))  As for car repairs being imminent vs unlikely, I can only go by literally decades of experience driving & working on them.  For the rest, it's simple math: unless you can invest at a higher rate than the interest, you will ALWAYS come out ahead by paying off the high-interest debt.

Comment: @jamesqf, I have a couple decades of working on cars as well as finances. I know how frequently 20+ year old cars break vs 10+ year old cars. I also know that I didn't get my finances fixed until I stopped spending on CCs and using cash/debit everywhere. If a person never stops charging their spending, they will never get out from under interest payments. If a person can manage to pay off their CCs every month to avoid interest, great, but it's rare. Google "cash safety net vs credit card" to see what people think, not just me.